# Mod Rewrite, convert subdirectory to query string?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to convert subdirectories to a search query. So basically:

```
example.com/pizza
```

would be converted to:

```
example.com/?s=pizza
```

I have a basic knowledge of htaccess and I have done similar things before, however this time I cannot make it work. This is the problem:

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /results/?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However when I point the rewrite target to the root the user is redirected to "example.com" without the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I rewrite "example.com/pizza" to "example.com/?s=pizza" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:.*)?/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*      /?s=%1                     [L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/parameter` with or without trailing slash.

To:

`http://example.com/?s=parameter`

All strings are assumed to be variable.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`.